# Sending e-mails from multiple accounts at once

Tags: email, email-client

Is there any way to configure an e-mail client in such a way that it sends a given message to a given recipient from more than one account at once? E.g. I have some 5 accounts configured, I type the message, send and it sends from all those accounts withing few seconds (only the time needed for re-logging passes). Please note I don't want to use it to mail bomb anyone, it's just an interesting feature which I haven't ever spotted in any mail client.

Comment: Interesting feature? There's no reason to do this, hence why it was probably never implemented (probably never even considered for implementation).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need, but who am I to argue. Except to absolutely make sure that an email arrives to circumvent spam filters. Or to participate in sweepstakes under different names and email addresses.

I sure as heck would not like to receive five emails by the same person. I don't know any email client that offers something like this. Except for Newsletter tools that allow random choosing of SMTP servers ([Supermailer](http://int.supermailer.de/)).

You could create a macro with any automation software that uses a command line mail client (like http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/) and sends the same message over different SMTP servers. Most email clients like Outlook and Thunderbird can be invoked through the command line.

If you want to use your existing client, you may want to create a GUI macro that loops until all the email accounts have been used. You could do something like that with AutoHotkey or AutoIt.